# Recreating Pinterest UI Flutter

Tags: user-interface, flutter, dart, user-experience, pinterest

How do I implement the long press peek and select an item with animation do with flutter I tried using onLongPressStart to track the long press and now how do I animate the icons popping up and hiding them when finger is released select them when hovering above them.[image: Hover Image]

And also how do make the Pinterest bottom navigation
[image: Bottom Navigation]

Answer (score 1):

The same animation already implemented with other naive solutions. The code logic is very similar. I suggest that you can take a look at it first and then implement it on Flutter.

eg.
https://github.com/brucetoo/PinterestView